# How to trigger ajax call based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am building coupon website. I need to trigger ajax action based on url of page. Let me explain.

For example, if user goes to page website_url/?coupon_id=99 - he gets page website_url and popup with ajax action inside it (ajax gets data for coupon post type with id=99 and show it's values).

If user goes to page website_url/page1/?coupon_id=99 - he gets page website_url/page1/ and the same popup.

You can see this logic in action on some coupon websites, for example, coupondunia.in

I created ajax action, it's working

```
function coupon_get_code(){
    $couponid = $_GET['couponid'];  
    $code = get_post( $couponid );
    if( !empty( $code ) ){
        $offer_coupon = get_post_meta( $code->ID, 'coupon', true );
        $response .= '<div class="coupon_modal_coupon">'.$offer_coupon.'</div>';
    }
    else{
        $response = __( 'Offer does not exists', 'textdomain' );
    }
    echo  $response ;
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_code', 'coupon_get_code');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_code', 'coupon_get_code');
```

Currently I made triggering ajax action based on click, like this

```
    // Coupon Modal
  $( '.offer_coupon.masked_coupon:not(.expired_coupon)' ).live("click", function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var couponid = $this.data('couponid'); 

    $.pgwModal({
        url: translation.ajax_url + "?action=ajax_code&couponid=" + couponid,
        titleBar: false,
        ajaxOptions : {
            success : function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    $.pgwModal({ pushContent: response });
                } else {
                    $.pgwModal({ pushContent: 'An error has occured' });
                }                
            }
        }
    });

  });
```

But how to trigger this ajax request based on url?

Comment: Have the function in dom ready so it runs soon as page loads. `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: This function is inside jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});

Comment: Yes but you also have it inside click handler move it out of it and into its own function say `popupload()` If you need to call it on click too call the function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found function which can help me. Testing now.

```
  function GetURLParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
      {
        return sParameterName[1];
      }
    }
  }
```

So my ajax trigger can be like this

```
  var coupontrigger = GetURLParameter("couponid");
  if(coupontrigger){
    $.pgwModal({
        url: translation.ajax_url + "?action=ajax_code&couponid=" + coupontrigger,
        titleBar: false,
        ajaxOptions : {
            success : function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    $.pgwModal({ pushContent: response });
                } else {
                    $.pgwModal({ pushContent: 'An error has occured' });
                }
            }
        }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the last number characters from the URL on page load (equal to the coupon id), instead of getting it on click from the data attribute.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  // Get the last numbers from the current page URL using Regex
  var couponid = window.location.href.match(/\d+$/);

  $.pgwModal({
    url: translation.ajax_url + "?action=ajax_code&couponid=" + couponid,
    titleBar: false,
    ajaxOptions : {
        success : function(response) {
            if (response) {
                $.pgwModal({ pushContent: response });
            } else {
                $.pgwModal({ pushContent: 'An error has occured' });
            }                
        }
    }
 });

});
```

Put the jQuery in a file named ajax-coupon.js and conditionally enqueue the script.

```
// Conditionally enqueue your script only if the template coupons.php is used to display the page.
function my_scripts_method() {

  // Register your script location, dependencies and version
  wp_register_script('ajax-coupon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-coupon.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );

  // Check if the current page is using coupons.php, if so, load the script.
  if ( is_page_template( 'coupons.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-coupon');
  }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Comment: I think about this, but such function will work on all pages of site. And what if user goes to simple page, without /?coupon_id=99 . As I understand, such function will get an error in this case

Comment: Just enqueue the script on necessary pages only. Since your using Wordpress, I assume you're using a custom post type for your coupons?

Comment: Yes, but coupon shows also from posts (with shortcode) and also can be displayed in sidebar by shortcodes.

Comment: Alright, but if a coupon is in a sidebar or post, then it will be triggered on click right? Your question is about triggering your popup based on the page URL. I've updated my answer to show how you can conditionally load the script to pages.

Comment: Example: user is on page website/post. He click on button and go to website/post?coupon_id=99 - but this is not a coupon page, he still on page with post, so script is not working in this case